# Angular - Encapsulate service inside component is a bad practice?

Tags: angular, design-patterns

Let's assume that i have `SoccerFieldComponent` that has provider that called `SoccerFieldService`

**SoccerFieldComponent:**

```
@Component({
 providers: [SoccerFieldService]
})
class SoccerFieldComponent extends Component {
//yada yada....
}
```

**SoccerFieldService:**

```
class SoccerFieldService {
//a lot of observables/functions that related to the soccer field component
}
```

Now let's assume that SoccerFieldComponent can be used multiple times in my complex system, the only thing that will be different is the component that wrapping him, let's give him the name `StadiumComponent`

**StadiumComponent:**

```
@Component({
 template: "some-complex-template-that-contains-stadium-field-component.html"
})
class StadiumComponent {
}
```

i would really like to expose some of the `SoccerFieldService` data outside the `SoccerFieldComponent` that the `StadiumComponent` could use it.

**My Current Solution:**

Inside the `StadiumComponent`:

```
@ViewChild(SoccerFieldComponent, {static: false})
    set soccerFieldComponent(componentRef: SoccerFieldComponent) {
        if (componentRef) {
            this.soccerFieldComponentRef = componentRef;
            this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
        }
    }
```

Inside the `SoccerFieldComponent`:

```
get currentScore$(): Observable<string> {
        return this.soccerFieldService.currentScore$.pipe(
            distinctUntilChanged(),
        );
    }
```

Now i can access through the component to specific observable inside the service.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest NOT provide service directly at component level. Instead wrap all the necessary components, services, pipes, directives etc. (those work as one unit) as module.

Following will be my approach:

```
@Injectable()
class SoccerFieldService {
  //a lot of observables/functions that related to the soccer field component

  currentScore$() {
    return of(0);
  }
}

@Component({
  providers: [SoccerFieldService]
})
class SoccerFieldComponent extends Component {

  constructor(soccerFieldService: SoccerFieldService)

  get currentScore$(): Observable<string> {
    return this.soccerFieldService.currentScore$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    );
  }
}

@Component({
  template: "some-complex-template-that-contains-stadium-field-component.html"
})
class StadiumComponent {
  @ViewChild(SoccerFieldComponent, { static: false })
  set soccerFieldComponent(componentRef: SoccerFieldComponent) {
    if (componentRef) {
      this.soccerFieldComponentRef = componentRef;
      this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    StadiumComponent,
    SoccerFieldComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    StadiumComponent,
    SoccerFieldComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    SoccerFieldService
  ]
})
export class SoccerFieldModule {
}
```

Import 'SoccerFieldModule' module where is required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Stadium component has no relation to the SoccerFieldModule.

Comment: @YochaiAkoka In that case, remove the "StadiumComponent" from module. And import the "SoccerFieldModule" where it is required (e.g. where StadiumComponent is part of). This way you can modularize the SoccerFieldComponent, its unit-tests etc.

Answer (score -1):

You are reinventing the wheel. Since `SoccerFieldService` is a service that you want use in multiple places, make it injectable and inject it where you need it. You can inject the same service instance to `StadumComponent` and `SoccerFieldComponent`. There is no need (duh - its just a bad design) to expose serivce via component only to allow other components to use it. Those components should use service directly.

Comment: But 90% of the logic inside the service will never be access through those components, it's not a bad design to just expose everything? @Antoniosss

Comment: Also the main reason for the SoccerFieldService is: 1.to reduce code in the SoccerFieldComponent  2.to make it easy to expose some of the data out, 3.each instance of the SoccerFieldComponent will need a new instance of the SoccerFieldService @Antoniosss

Comment: If you are worried about access scope you can split that service into 2 separate services or wrap that service into "light" version of it that exposes (and delegates) only required methods. In any of those cases, sharing it via component is just nuts.

Comment: Your description (2nd comment) says it is not a "service" per se but rather utility class - it is literally part of your component, just split into separate class.

Comment: It isn't a utility class, the SoccerFieldComponent is responsible to update data inside the service, i could do it in the component also (aka reducing code, share of responsibility) each SoccerFieldComponent have to create a new SoccerFieldService instance, this is why it most be provide in the SoccerFieldComponent level.

Comment: That is the reason why it is just an util, not "service" - it is literally part of your component and I would say to keep it that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202125/discussion-between-yochai-akoka-and-antoniossss).

Comment: The idea of having injectable services is to keep hermetized code as injectable instances that can be accessible by multiple parts of your application - in your scenario 2 different components - without manually propagating them across system (or making it static singleton). If some of your code is sharable, make it injectable and inject where you need it. If not (in your case it is not) keep it in component or helper class (like you did) that is staticly bound to that component (your case)

Comment: Now you try to make "shareable" part of your code exposed via component instead of making it injectable. Bad practice - but will work eventually.

Comment: Please add code example to your answer. The requirements are pretty simple: 1.The SoccerFieldComponent should new instance of SoccerFieldService each time, 2.i want to access to the value of the specific SoccerFieldService instance from the parent component.

Comment: *The requirements are pretty simple:* and the answer is simple, keep that in component - its not a service in widely known and agreed manner.